How to create an uncontrolled checkbox component in React Native?
The biggest question is how to manage and update the state of this component internally through the DOM without using the useState hook? How to do re-rendering?
I've been researching a lot on the Internet, but what I see most is the use of a component that is already native and has a ready-made implementation like TextInput, and there's no way to know how these components do this. In the case of CheckBox, most searches return a controlled component. I only found it for pure React because it has the native component that by default is not controlled.

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const UncontrolledCheckbox = ({ label, onChange }) => {
  const isCheckedRef = useRef(false);

  const toggleCheckbox = () => {
    isCheckedRef.current = !isCheckedRef.current;
    onChange?.(isCheckedRef.current); // Notify parent if needed
    forceUpdateUI(); // Trigger UI re-render
  };

  const [visualState, setVisualState] = React.useState(false); // Only for UI re-render
  const forceUpdateUI = () => setVisualState((prev) => !prev);

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={toggleCheckbox}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={[
            styles.checkbox,
            isCheckedRef.current && styles.checkboxChecked,
          ]}
        />
        <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  checkbox: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#000',
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  checkboxChecked: {
    backgroundColor: '#007BFF',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default UncontrolledCheckbox;


Thanks for your answer, but you are using state the same way. The only difference is that in addition to the state you are using useRef. I know that uncontrolled components use Refs. Now I don't know if they also use states. If these components use states too, then would the only difference between controlled and uncontrolled be that the state of one is internal and the other is external? According to my research I didn't see anything talking about them using states.
